# Asp.NetCore FallbackPolicy for Multiple IDPs

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, openid-connect, asp.net-authorization

I'm building a set of Web Apis using .Net6.0 that will have more than one Identity Provider.  I would like to have a FallbackPolicy that means all endpoints will have to at least have authenticated requests.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to get the FallBackPolicy to work as it always results in a 401.

When I use the DefaultPolicy with the [Authorize] it does work

```
public void Configure(WebApplication app)
{
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    app
        .UseNSwagExceptInProductionAndStaging()
        .UseHttpsRedirection()
        .UseAuthentication()
        .UseRouting()
        .UseCors(DevelopmentCorsPolicy)
        .UseAuthorization()
        .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
        });
}
```

```
public static IServiceCollection AddJwtAuthenticationSupport(
    this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
    WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var idpSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("IdentityProviders").Get<IdentityProviders>();
    var jwtSettingsSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings").Get<JwtSettings>();
    OidcProviderModel oidcProvider;
    if (!builder.Environment.IsProduction() && !builder.Environment.IsStaging())
    {
        oidcProvider = idpSection.OidcProviders.Single(x => x.Name.Equals("Development"));
    }
    else
    {
        oidcProvider = idpSection.OidcProviders.First(x => !x.Name.Equals("Development"));
    }
    
    foreach (var jwtSetting in jwtSettingsSection.JwsSettings)
    {
        var authenticationBuilder = serviceCollection.AddAuthentication(jwtSetting.Issuer);
        authenticationBuilder.AddJwtBearer(jwtSetting.Issuer, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = oidcProvider.OidcSettings.Authority;
            options.Audience = jwtSetting.Audience;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = oidcProvider.OidcSettings.Authority,
                ValidAudience = jwtSetting.Audience,
                ValidateAudience = true
            };
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
            {
                
                OnMessageReceived = (context) =>
                {
                    var principal = context.Principal;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    var exception = context.Exception;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    var principal = context.Principal;
                    context.Success();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                    
                },
                OnForbidden = (context) =>
                {
                    var principal = context.Principal;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
    }
    
    return serviceCollection;
}
```

```
var authenticationSchemes = configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings").Get<JwtSettings>().JwsSettings.Select(s => s.Issuer).ToArray();
serviceCollection.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(authenticationSchemes)
        .Build();

    options
        .AddFeaturePermissionLevelPolicies<SiteUserAuthorizationRequirement, SiteFeature, PermissionLevel>(
            (feature, permissionLevel) => new SiteUserAuthorizationRequirement(feature, permissionLevel));
});
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to set up your own identity provider (e.g. with IdentityServer4) and have that one use OpenId Connect to use the identity providers you want to connect to?

Comment: I am using IdentityServer4 ... what I want to do is swap Idps in and out using config and have more than one

Comment: How about intercepting each of your Idp authentication events and injecting custom claim that you can later use for your policy?

Answer (score 0):

So ... I have just found out that:

```cs
serviceCollection.TryAddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, SiteUserAuthorizationHandler>();
```

does not work (this Authorization handler will hit the database for all those of you wondering)

```cs
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, SiteUserAuthorizationHandler>(); // ALWAYS USE .AddScoped DO NOT use .TryAddScoped
```

This does not solve the problem of the Fallback policy not working though.